# Unable to add images to content "Image field is required"

Tags: media

Developing a new site with Drupal 8, I was attempting to add an image to a custom block. In the editor I clicked the image icon and got a dialog to upload an image. After specifying a file (making sure it was within the upload file size), I got a strange error "Image field is required."

I took the error message literally, and created a new custom block type, adding a field of type "image" to the block. So now in the form, I have a Body and an Image field. If I try to upload using the "image" field below the body, I get the same error "Image field is required."

[image: Error message when attempting to insert an image]

I tried again using the Content / Media tab, to add an image file, and get the same error:

[image: Error on media upload]

(I also notice that there's a "Caption" checkbox but no field to enter a caption. I'm assuming I'll have a text field once the image is uploaded.)

Drupal 8.8, all current.

Comment: Did you check the error log at `/admin/reports/dblog`? Perhaps your system does not have `write permission` or proper `group/owner` to put uploaded image in the `/sites/default/files` folder.

Comment: Yes, thank you, there are no error messages in /admin/reports/dblog related to this, and the files directory is writable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message appears to be a red herring. Even though I thought I had fixed the nginx upload file size limit, I found that it was still at the default of 1mb. I fixed the upload limits to be sufficiently large in both nginx and php, and I was able to successfully add media content.